# Is it possible to exclude reference arguments in a generic function?

Tags: generics, reference, rust, traits

Since the generic type parameter `T` can be of any type, including a reference, I was wondering if it was possible to opt out of references in generic functions, i.e. to be able to write something like:

```
use std::ops::Deref;

fn foo<T: !Deref>(x: T) -> T {}
```

This, however, is not allowed and breaks already at the parsing stage.

I read about [`optin_builtin_traits`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/13231), but it only supports opting out of auto traits, so it wouldn't work either, because `Deref` is not an auto trait.

Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Why? If your function can operate on any type, why shouldn't it operate on a reference?

Comment: @DanHulme it's just an example case; I'm also interested in how to exclude other traits in general.

Comment: @DanHulme in addition, by ensuring the compiler that references are out of scope I could possibly exclude some lifetime issues.

Comment: I don't think there's anyway to do this. It doesn't seem that useful because unlike adding constraints (which allow you to call methods defined on the trait), negative constraints in general don't give you any more power than simply omitting the trait in the first place. Having this feature would also lead to surprising things. Simply implementing a trait for a type could be a breaking change.

Comment: @ljedrz What lifetime issues are you running into? Having `!Deref` wouldn't help you with resolving those anyway. This kind of feels like an XY problem to me.

Comment: @WesleyWiser an example would be a slight modification of a case from a [recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49918896/the-parameter-type-t-may-not-live-long-enough), where lifetime annotation would not be necessary if it weren't for the possibility of reference arguments: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=6332eaf0ed4248fc4ac3b8a7dcd88654&version=stable).

Comment: @ljedrz While that answer talks a lot about `T` being a reference, I believe the same situation applies if `T` *contains* a reference. Ie: `struct S<'a> { val: &'a str }`. The compiler has to make sure that any value of the type `T` will remain valid for the lifetime of the thing you're returning. I could be incorrect here though...

Comment: @WesleyWiser nope, [doesn't work](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=feefd003e39310936c79d0f22d185dbd&version=nightly).

Comment: @ljedrz I'm not sure what you mean. The playground link you've provided is exactly the case I'm talking about.

Comment: @WesleyWiser ah, I thought you meant that this *wouldn't* apply to objects containing references. I'm ok with this outcome (i.e. that nested references also don't work).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use auto traits for this:

```
#![feature(auto_traits)]
#![feature(negative_impls)]

auto trait NotReference {}

impl<'a, T> !NotReference for &'a T {}
impl<'a, T> !NotReference for &'a mut T {}

fn no_references<T: NotReference>(_: T) {}

fn main() {
    no_references(42); // OK
    no_references(&42); // the trait bound `&{integer}: NotReference` is not satisfied
    no_references("hello"); // the trait bound `&str: NotReference` is not satisfied

    no_references(vec![1, 2, 3]); // OK

    let x = vec![1, 2, 3];
    no_references(x.iter()); // the trait bound `&{integer}: NotReference` is not satisfied in `std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>`
}
```

Note that this also precludes:

- references with the `'static` lifetime, as shown by the "hello" call
- any struct which *contains* a reference as well, as shown by the `iter()` call

> I could possibly exclude some lifetime issues.

Practically, that's what the `'static` bound does:

```
fn foo<T: 'static>(x: T) -> T {}
```

Comment: @ljedrz ewww... rustfmt [*removes the `auto`* when it formats](https://github.com/rust-lang-nursery/rustfmt/issues/2637)! Fixed now, sorry.

Comment: Neat; since I thought `auto` was reserved for existing `std` traits I was trying to work something out with `Deref`. This workaround might come in handy.

Comment: Sure, it's possible. However, what's the point? As @Wesley Wiser says, a user could always do `struct S<'a> { val: &'a str }`.

Comment: Note that the auto-trait solution will also reject any types which "contains" a reference e.g. the `S<'a>` other people mentioned. Meanwhile, a `'static` bound will allow `&'static T`.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Could I not implement the auto-trait manually for a struct wrapping a reference?